# Should I save the download url or the path of images in my database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

After user uploads an image, should I at this point call `getDownloadUrl()` and store that url `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/myimage.jpg?alt=media&token=mytoken` in my database, or should I just save the path `/dir/file.jpg` and call it later when it's time to display the image?

I would assume it's better to just store the url because there will be more reads than writes, so I can just show the image without another fetch for each of them. What is better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to store both.  You'll want to url in order to easily load the image later, and you'll want the path in case you want to delete the record in the database, and also delete the file in storage using the Admin SDK.

Comment: Why I didn't I think of both!? Genius!! Thanks!